# UICollectonView cells move to next column

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that has a bunch of small images in cells. My problem is that cells are going horizontally and will keep going off of the screen to the right. I want them to wrap around to the next line when they run out of space.

Right now I am using a horizontal flow. I have messed around with scrolling and other settings but I can not get them to move to the next row. Here is an example of what it looks like right now:
[image]

Comment: Are you using autolayout and storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I am using both.

Comment: It sounds like the frame of your collection view isn't correct. You need to set constraints so that the collection view is the same width as the controller's view.

Comment: yeah, you need fix the size of the collection view or fix the edges, or both

Comment: Increase height of collection view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had things flopped. I have these two (fixed) functions:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.imageURLArray.count;
}
```

The values in the functions was flipped around so that numberOfSectionsInCollectionView was equal to the count and that the other one was returning 1.